# Un-/hiding options of a Select depending on value of another Select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Disclaimer: This seems to have been asked in similar form several times already but none of the solutions has worked for me. Additionally most of the solutions appear to be 4+ years old (up to 12+), who knows what changed in that time, I certainly don't.

The Problem: I want to hide all options in a select and only "unhide" them depending on what is chosen in another select.

I have two selects:

```
<select id="pool" name="pool" onchange="cause_mod()">
    <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Pool</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

and:

```
<select id="cause" name="cause">
    <option value="none" selected hidden="true">cause/option>
    <option value="sale" hidden="true">sale</option>
    <option value="withdraw" id="withdraw" hidden>withdraw</option>
    <option value="deposit" style="display: none">deposit</option>
</select>
```

The three different variances are to show what i have already tried on the select-side.

I shan't post every variation of the javascript code as it simply would be too much. I will post three variations that i tried with the three variations in the second select:

```
function cause_mod(){
    var pool = document.getElementById("pool");
    var cause = document.getElementById("cause");
    var deposit = document.querySelectorAll('option[value="deposit"]');
    if(pool.value === "1"){
        cause.options[1].setAttribute("hidden", true)
        document.getElementById("withdraw").removeAttribute("hidden")
        deposit.style.display = "";
    }
    else if(pool.value === "2"){
        pretty much the opposite
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any convenient method (although at this point I'll take inconvenient as well) to "grab" individual options from a select in order to .dosomething with it.

Answer (score 0):

[The `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) shouldn't be set to the JavaScript Boolean `true`, it should just be present or set to the string `"hidden"`:

```js
const sel = document.querySelector("select");
sel.options[1].setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
  <option>Item 3</option>  
</select>
```

Now, if you have an `option` that should not have any value, set it to: `value=""`, not `value="none"` because `none` is a string and therefore will become the value of the element.

Also, setting the [CSS `style.display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to an empty string is not acceptable as this attribute should be set to a valid CSS `display` value.

Additionally, `querySelectorAll()` returns a node list, which is an array-like object. Node lists don't have a `value` property. In your case, if you are looking for a single element on your page, use `querySelector()`, which will return the first element that matches the selector you supply or `undefined` if no match can be found. When there is a match, you can then access its DOM properties, like `value`.

Lastly, you should move your `pool`, `cause` and `deposit` variable declarations out of your function so that they are reinitialized each time the function is called, this is a wasted of resources to scan for the same elements that you already scanned for earlier.

Comment: 1. the "none" is supposed to hide the options, an empty string wqould show them again. 2. with querySelector() i only get "null" as element instead of the element. 3. done

Comment: alright, if I use getElementById instead of querySelector() it actually works and i can set or remove attributes. Thanks!

Comment: @Knolfuns As you can see from my code above, `querySelector()` works just fine, but you were using `querySelectorAll()` which as I describe above isn't the same thing. Also, setting `display` to an empty string is not valid for that CSS property (see the link).